# Creating a new Keyboard in Android

Tags: android-softkeyboard

I am trying to create a non-roman keyboard for Android. Non-roman meaning that the characters will be different symbols (for Tibetan) which are not supported by Android. 
My question: is it possible to create a keyboard which will be supported all through Android? In the way that if I switch to this keyboard will allow me to write in this particular language in any application or write notes, etc. 
In iOS it is possible but I haven't seen it in Android.

I was looking at http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615 where they define the keys:

```
 <Row>
        <Key android:codes="49" android:keyLabel="1" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:codes="50" android:keyLabel="2"/>
        <Key android:codes="51" android:keyLabel="3"/>
        <Key android:codes="52" android:keyLabel="4"/>
        <Key android:codes="53" android:keyLabel="5"/>
</Row>
```

How can I define the keys if they are not Roman characters? Also I should be able to connect some font type where the characters are defined, where I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can make your own keyboard application the system default, there are lots of applications doing exactly this already, like [Swype](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nuance.swype.dtc) or [Swiftkey](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.touchtype.swiftkey).

[Here is a guide](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615) for this. The most relevant part is the manifest file, which tells Android that your application provides a keyboard service, and you can set it as your own keyboard in the *Settings*.

Update:

The `android:codes` XML attribute, according to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard.Key.html#attr_android:codes) means:

> The unicode value or comma-separated values that this key outputs.
>
> May be a string value, using `'\\;'` to escape characters such as `'\\n'` or `'\\uxxxx'` for a unicode character.
>
> May be an integer value, such as `"100"`.

So you should use the Unicode character option. For example, the Hungarian letter `ő` could be achieved by `\\u0151`. For finding out the Unicode characters you need, you could use [this online service](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/).

Comment: Thank you meskobalazs. I added more info to my post based on the link that you mentioned, please review it.